# Posting JSON Array Collection to Asp.net Core Web API

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, asp.net-core-webapi

Need your expertises 
I am working with JS & Asp.net Core Web API.
I am trying to post a JSON Array to my API but i am failing to get data in web api post method it is NULL every time need help in understanding  what is that I am missing..

Below is JS Code

```
function Trails(){   
var A = [];
var B = [];
var MyData = [];

for(var i = 0;i <= 2;i++){
    var _A = {
        "ID" : i,
        "_A" : "A"+i
    };
    A.push(_A);
}    

for(var i = 0;i <= 2;i++){
    var _B = {
        "ID" : i,
        "_B" : "B"+i
    };
    B.push(_B);
}      

for(var i = 0;i <= 2;i++){
    MyData.push({
        "MyDataName" : "CJ"+i,
        "A" : A,
        "B" : B,
    });
}       

$.ajax({  
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",  
    url: "https://localhost:44359/api/values/",  
    contentType: "application/json",
    data :JSON.stringify({MyData}), 
    dataType: "json",  
    success: function (data) {                      
        alert(data);          
    }, //End of AJAX Success function  
    failure: function (data) {  
        alert(data.responseText); 
        console.log(data); 
    }, //End of AJAX failure function  
    error: function (data) {  
        alert(data.responseText);  
        console.log(data); 
    } //End of AJAX error function  
});
```

}

C# Classes

```
 public class A
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string _A { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string _B { get; set; }
}

public class MyData
{
    public string MyDataName { get; set; }
    public List<A> A { get; set; }
    public List<B> B { get; set; }

}
```

Web API Post method

```
 // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] List<MyData> MyData)
    {

    }
```

MyData is always null. please help

Comment: Change this line `data :JSON.stringify({MyData}),` to `data :JSON.stringify(MyData),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using: `JSON.stringify({MyData})` instead of `JSON.stringify(MyData)`. It goes to the server as a JSON containing field "MyData" with MyData, instead of just MyData array.